# CSS and Jquery Hover

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, hover, show-hide

**Edit**:  Before this edit, I was asking for solutions involving CSS.  I was notified that I would need Javascript to complete the following tasks

**Description**:  I have a class (profile-inner) that displays a member's complete profile.  It's background color is white.  I have gotten a hover to work for profile-inner.  It's background color is gray.  There is the link "Comment" in class "profile-footer".  When it is clicked, it toggles the class "inline-profile-comment" (expand/collapse).

**Problem**:  The "profile-inner" hover selects the whole container including toggled class "inline-profile-comment".  I do not want this.  I only want the hover when "inline-profile-comment" is not shown.

**Html**:

```
<div class="profile-inner">
  an entire profile

    <div class="profile-footer">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<%= profile_item.id %>_comment">
       Comment</a> 
       <ul><li>lots of list items etc</li></ul>

       <div class="inline-profile-comment">
      <div id="<%= profile_item.id %>_comment" class="show collapse">
     The comment form
   </div></div>

 </div></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.profile-inner {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.profile-inner:hover {
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I hope I have explained it good enough.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no hidden element selector in CSS. If you want the hover effect on `.profile-inner` only when `inline-profile-comment` is hidden, you would need javascript.

Comment: I thought this would be so, I should have noted that I realized this possibility.  I will edit this question for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this if you `add/remove` a class after the toggle happened and change the `css` selector for hover to that `class`, like

**JS**

```
$('.profile-inner').toggleClass('hover');
$('.profile-footer a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.inline-profile-comment').toggle('fast',function(){
        $('.profile-inner').toggleClass('hover');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
profile-inner {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.profile-inner.hover:hover {
    background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.inline-profile-comment{ display:none; }
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Awaz/3/).

Comment: I will implement this in my code now and let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks brother, works great.  But there is one interference.  The application is a Ruby app, and I am using twitter bootstrap gem.  It has built in Javascript to fire the show collapse fuction.  How can I escape the built in function and use this one?  Because I think the two are interfering because the toggle isn't smooth.

Comment: You are welcome and I think if you remove `class="show collapse"` fromk the div then it may stop conflict.

Comment: It works great in Fiddle.  But js has taught me that I have messy html, haha.  I am having to clean up a little bit.  I am new to Ruby and I am rendering these forms, so the html can get real messy (as it has now) if I don't watch what I am doing.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but I have been working on this since I received your reply and there is one minor issue that I can't seem to work out.  Everything goes well when it toggles:  it loses its hover and changes cursors.  The problem is when I click the text-field in the comment box, it toggles the hover.  What is weird is that I can click everywhere near the comment box and this won't happen, but once the text-field has been clicked, it toggles the hover class.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: Haha, just as I asked I found the answer.  I had a tool-tip anchored to my text-field, hence why the hover was being toggled! :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of concept. I'm a big fan of toggling states on an object's main element, in this case your profile-inner. Essentially what we do is use the 'hide-comment' state to define our CSS rules, toggling the comment form and hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/NgzU6/

Comment: I am using all these answers' solutions right now, I will let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I have utilized this code in another section of my application :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you have, plus add this:

```
.profile-inner:hover .inline-profile-comment {
    background-color: Whatever it should be; }
```

Comment: Yes, but I am wanting to lose the hover all together when said class is toggled.  Thanks for your help though. :)

Comment: Sorry, mis-read your initial question... the js solution by amustill is how I would do it then.